# Relative clause starting with "in which way"

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

I made the following sentence:

> 1. It is crucial for us to be attentive to the true needs and wants of our hearts. Only in this way can we attain a life that aligns with our self-expectations.

I want to know if I can combine these two sentences into one by using a relative clause:

> 2. It is crucial for us to be attentive to the true needs and wants of our hearts，only in **which way** can we attain a life that aligns with our self-expectations.

Comment: Hi ForOU, I wrote an answer, but in the future please [describe the research that you've done on the issue](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). In this case, knowing that would have helped me to gauge how much detail to include (particularly in paragraphs #1 and #3), whether to provide more background (e.g., about how relative clauses work), etc. In the absence of that information, I tried my best.

Comment: @MarcInManhattam  Thank you. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically, your revision is fine. However, there are some issues:

1. It is correct to place the adverb "only" before what it modifies. However, that position is a bit unusual for an adverb, so the sentence doesn't sound entirely natural.
2. The relative adjective "which" doesn't seem to have a referent. Which way is meant? We can infer something like "the way in which we are attentive to the true needs . . .", but there is no specific adjectival phrase to which "which" directly corresponds. Some people might consider that an error; even if you considered it acceptable, I believe that it would still make the sentence sound somewhat awkward.
3. As with #1 above, the sub-aux inversion is grammatically correct but may sound unnatural to some readers.

Comment: I'd say the revision is unacceptable since it contains two main clauses separated by just a comma.

Comment: @Billb . The relative word "which" would make the second clause a subordinate one to the first, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ForOU No: in your example, "which" is not a relative pronoun, but a determiner that belongs with "way". The expression beginning with "only" is not subordinate but a main clause that could stand alone. Subordinate clauses cannot normally do that.

Comment: @BillJ  But there are examples like *I said that it might be more efficient to hold the meeting on Saturday morning, **which suggestion** they all enthusiastically endorsed* . 
 where "which"  is a relative word and, at the same time, a determiner.

Comment: @ForOU Please note that BillJ is describing an alternative way of analyzing that clause. There is no English Academy, and there is no single correct way of analyzing English sentences in general. (I believe that the way that he is describing is advocated by [CaGEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cambridge_Grammar_of_the_English_Language), if you're interested.)

Comment: It has nothing to do with CGEL; rather, it's a simple case of comma splice.

Comment: @ForOU In your new example, the relative phrase is not clause-initial, which rules it out as being a supplementary relative clause.

Comment: @BillJ  What do you mean by not clause-initial？ It is at the initial position of the relative clause(or pre nucleus position). And it is from CGEL.

Comment: @ForOU I was referring to your example 2. in your original question, where "which way" is not clause-initial. In your example above, the relative phrase, "which suggestion" is clause-initial, so the clause is relative one.

Comment: @Billi  Oh, I see.  What if the relative phrase is "in which way" as a whole？ There are analogous examples from the other CGEL(by Quirk et al) *4.  The plane may be several hours late, **in which case** there is no point in our waiting*

Comment: @ForOU The relative phrase "in which case" is clause-initial.

Comment: @BillJ It's not a comma-splice if the part after the comma is not a main clause, and if CGEL says that it's a main clause (as you seem to be suggesting), then yes that interpretation differs from others.

Comment: @Billb hm... You seems to be suggesting that "not clause-initial" problem of (2) is because of the presence of "only", but I think that "only" can be treated as part of the relative phrase itself, with "only" modifying PP. (2) may be unnatural, as Marcln pointed out, but I don't think it can be ruled out by not clause-initial.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Forget CGEL. I'm saying that it is a main clause. One only has to read it to sense that. Importantly, "in which way" is not clause-initial since it's preceded by the adverb "only", which triggers subject-aux inversion.

Comment: @BillJ OK, then we simply differ in opinion. When I read it, I sense that it is a relative clause. And "only" modifies the prepositional phrase "in which way" so that the entire adverbial phrase "only in which way" occupies a clause-initial position.

Comment: You can treat it as a supplementary relative construction consisting of a separate sentence that should be preceded by a terminal point, and commenced with a capital letter.

Comment: @BillJ Your opinion is noted. Thank you for offering it.

Answer (score 0):

> 2. It is crucial for us to be attentive to the true needs and wants of our hearts, only in **which way** can we attain a life that aligns with our self-expectations.

@BillJ is right; *which* is not a relative pronoun here; it is a determiner introducing *way*.

To solve the comma splice problem @BillJ highlighted,  we add a coordinating conjunction.

I prefer a slight simplification, with pronoun replacing the preposition+determiner+noun structure.

> It is crucial for us to be attentive to the true needs and wants of our hearts, [and] only **which** can we attain a life that aligns with our self-expectations.

*which*, now as a pronoun, represents the entire preceding clause.

Comment: but "which"  can be a determiner and , at the same time, a relative word.  Someone might call it a **relative determiner.**  eg *I said that it might be more efficient to hold the meeting on Saturday morning, **which suggestion** they all enthusiastically endorsed*